# How to reset origin feature branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a develop branch
And feature initWork branch,I push my changes in github
But after log I see that the origin/feature/initWork behind 1 commit
So what can I do here
To put the origin/feature/initWork on the top

Comment: Are you asking about `git push origin feature/initWork`?.. Please **do not post errors as image**, this is a very bad idea - those who use a screen reader cannot understand it, and search engines struggle to parse such data. Please [edit] to include your terminal output as code block.

Comment: yes i ask about git push origin feature/initWork

Answer (score 1):

The output in log where `origin/somebranch` is below `somebranch` means that you have some local changes which are not integrated to the remote repository. To sync from local to remote (remote is `origin` in this case, but may differ for other scenarios - say, `upstream` is popular for original repo when you work on a forked one), you can use `push` command:

```bash
git push origin feature/initWork

# general:
# git push $REMOTE $BRANCH
```